# .focus() does not work because dynamic table not loaded yet - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am dynamically creating a table using data from an AJAX call.  I am using a "select/dropdown box" .on('change') function to send values to my PHP. Once the table displays, I want to set focus to a search box dynamically created on the table.

The trouble seems to be that since the table takes a couple seconds to become visible, the .focus() command fires before the table is visible.  I would like to have the .focus() command fire after the create table function completes.

Javascript/Jquery Code:

```
$('#t6F3Box1').on('change', function()
    {   
        var $newTable ='<table id="tempEmployerTbl" class="studentTables"><thead><tr>';
        var $searchStr=new RegExp("ID");
        var $tableContainerDiv="#t6F3TableCont";
        var $rowFlag=0;
        var $responseDataValue=[]
        var $employerState=$('#t6F3Box1').val();
        var $getTableDataPhp="../application/employer.php";
        var $data=[];

            $('#t6F3ErrDiv').text('');
            $('#t6F3TableCont, #t6F3HLine2, #t6F3HLine2').show();

        $data += "&employerState=" + encodeURIComponent($employerState);

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url:  $getTableDataPhp,
        cache: false,
        datatype: 'json',
        data: $data,
        success: function($responseData)
        {

            //Loop through the responsdata returned in a JSON Array
            //dynamically create the Employer drop down box 
            if (!$responseData.authenticationError)
            {
                    //Create the header for the Employer Table
                    $.each($responseData, function($key, $value) 
                    {
                        if($rowFlag==0)
                        {
                            $responseDataValue=$responseData[$key];
                            $.each($responseDataValue, function($keys, $values)
                            {
                                if ($searchStr.test($keys))
                                {

                                    $newTable += '<th class="tableDataHide">'  + $keys + '</th>';

                                }
                                    else
                                {

                                    $newTable += '<th class="tableDataShow">'  + $keys + '</th>'
                                }           


                            });
                            $rowFlag=1;
                        }
                    });
                $newTable +='</tr></thead><tbody>';

                //Create the body for the Employer Table
                $.each($responseData, function($key, $value) 
                {
                    $newTable +=  '<tr>'
                    $responseDataValue=$responseData[$key];
                    $.each($responseDataValue, function($keys, $values)
                    {   
                        if ($searchStr.test($keys))
                        {

                            $newTable += '<td class="tableDataHide">'  + $values + '</td>';

                        }
                            else
                        {
                            if($values==null)
                            {
                                $values="";
                            }
                            $newTable += '<td class="tableDataShow">'  + $values + '</td>'
                        }           

                    }); 

                    $newTable +='</tr>';


                }); 

                $newTable +='</tbody></table>';
                $($tableContainerDiv).html($newTable); 

                $("#tempEmployerTbl").dataTable();
$('#tblSearchBox').focus();

            }               
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see where the `.focus()` event is setup in your code. Beside that, you have two possible options: (1) Attach the event handler after the table is appened or (2) delegate the event so when the element is added dynamically, jQuery attaches the event handler for you. For more information on the latter, check the api docs for [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) depending on what version of jQuery you are running.

Comment: My apologies, I have reinserted the .focus command where it was when the code didn't work. When the.focus() is inserted here, it completes the focus before the table has a chance to load on the HTML page. I have attempted to both bind functions to this even as well as using event listeners to the on change function but to no avail.

Comment: It wont bug out but you should fix $data. It's initialized as an array, then has a string concat used on it.

Comment: @MatthewWitt That's where the delegation comes into play. Create the event handler using `.on()` or `.delegate()`. When the content is changed in the element, jQuery will automatically attach the event for you at the proper time. From the jQuery api docs for `.delegate()`: **Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements.**

Comment: @war10ck Per the API docs:As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods.

Comment: I am currently running Jquery 1.9.1

Comment: @MatthewWitt So use the `.on()` method to delegate your event handler...I noted that in my first comment. It depends on your jQuery version. View the jQuery api docs for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Look in the heading **Direct and delegated events**.

Comment: @War10ck - My apologies but I think that I am missing something here.  My "change" event is an .on change event.  Could you please give me a brief example as to how I am to use .on with .focus?

Comment: @MatthewWitt Sorry buddy, I don't mean to be confusing. You attach it to a parent element and provide a selector for children you want to delegate it to like so `$($tableContainerDiv).on('focus', $('#tblSearchBox'), null, function () { //place code related to what happens when event is fired here });`

Comment: @MatthewWitt The above code should dynamically attach the event handler for when the child element is focused on in the future, even though it doesn't currently exist.

Comment: {$("#t6F3TableCont").on('focus', $('#tblSearchBox'), null, function () {
 alert ('testing'); 
});}

Comment: Thanks for the patience, as you can see from my last comment, I inserted an alert to test when the child element received .focus but the alert never occurred.  Not sure if this still has something to do with the fact that the table hadn't been created yet so the .focus command didn't know where to put focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you even call `.focus` in your example, but the solution is simply to call it after the `$($tableContainerDiv).html($newTable);` -- i.e. after it's appended by the ajax callback.

Comment: My apologies, I have reinserted the .focus command where it was when the code didn't work.  When the.focus() is inserted here, it completes the focus before the table has a chance to load on the HTML page.  I have attempted to both bind functions to this even as well as using event listeners to the on change function but to no avail.

Comment: @MatthewWitt you could possibly try binding it to one of these: http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks but from what I can tell it should be sequential